# Is there something wrong with my OnLocationChanged?

Tags: java, android, gps, location

My location Logger Service class does not provide me with updated informations about my location. Is there something wrong with me OnLocationChanged?

```
public class LocationLoggerService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    Location location; // location
    String towers;

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    public LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        ourLocation();
        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        towers = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

        // Just af test here:
        String hej1 = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        String hej2 = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fra Oncreate: /nLat: " + hej1 + "Long: " + hej2,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void ourLocation()

    {
        // Find my current location
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                2000, 0, this);
    }
```

onLocationChanged method does not provide me with new informations. I tried out with some test(toast), but its like it does not read this method.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    if (loc != null) {
        // Testing the position
        String hej3 = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
        String hej4 = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, "loc: " + "Lat: " + hej3 + "Long: " + hej4,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onDestroy();

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // this service will run until we stop it

        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

My manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />


<service
        android:name="LocationLoggerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="LocationLoggerService" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the code as below and try again, get the location object directly from the onLocationChanged callback method... I am hoping you are moving to test this functionality.
location ojbect will contains the latest latitude and longitude.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    // Testing onLocationChanged:
    String hej1 = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
    String hej2 = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location: "+"Lat: " + hej1 + "Long: " + hej2,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String hej3 = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
    String hej4 = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, "loc: " +"Lat: " + hej3 + "Long: " + hej4,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: Are you moving or sitting in the same location? OnLocationChanged will be triggerred when you move. You can make one small change in your application for testing purpose,ocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                0, 0, this); then later you can revert to 2000... Once you install this chnage in your device, walk for 10 mins and you will observe the new locations